# App crash only on iPhone Device and not in Simulator - Xamarin Binding project

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

I created iOS Binding Project with two static lib to SDK Payleven (github.com/payleven/mPOS-SDK-iOS). App crash only on iPhone Device and not in Simulator. On Simulator app works fine.

In "iOS Build" I set the same settings for iPhone and Simulator. The only difference is "Supported architecture:"

iPhone: ARMv7 + ARMv7s + ARM64

Simulator: i386 + x86_64

I try all configurations in "Linker behavior".

Without additional mtouch arguments in IOS Build I have 34  errors
http://pastebin.com/03S6P9DU

with arguments

```
-gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir}/Soft.ePosPayleven/ -lPaylevenSDK -lAdyenToolkit -force_load ${ProjectDir}/Soft.ePosPayleven/libPaylevenSDK.a ${ProjectDir}/Soft.ePosPayleven/libAdyenToolkit.a"
```

I have this exception http://pastebin.com/8eEMrU0n  in class generated by xamarin in binding project.

```
[CompilerGenerated]
        [EditorBrowsable (EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        [Export ("init")]
        public PLVPayleven () : base (NSObjectFlag.Empty)
        {
            IsDirectBinding = GetType ().Assembly == global::ApiDefinition.Messaging.this_assembly;
            if (IsDirectBinding) {
exception-->    InitializeHandle (global::ApiDefinition.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend (this.Handle, global::ObjCRuntime.Selector.GetHandle ("init")), "init");
            } else {
                InitializeHandle (global::ApiDefinition.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper (this.SuperHandle, global::ObjCRuntime.Selector.GetHandle ("init")), "init");
            }
        }
```

libAdyenToolkit.linkwith.cs

```
[assembly: LinkWith ("libAdyenToolkit.a", LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.ArmV7s | LinkTarget.Simulator | LinkTarget.Simulator64 | LinkTarget.Arm64, SmartLink = true, ForceLoad = true, 
     Frameworks = "CoreFoundation CoreData CoreLocation ExternalAccessory SystemConfiguration UIKit Foundation", LinkerFlags = "-lz -lsqlite3", IsCxx = true)]
```

libPaylevenSDK.linkwith.cs

```
[assembly: LinkWith ("libPaylevenSDK.a", LinkTarget.Simulator | LinkTarget.Simulator64 | LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.Arm64, SmartLink = true, ForceLoad = true, 
     Frameworks = "CoreFoundation CoreData CoreLocation ExternalAccessory SystemConfiguration UIKit Foundation", LinkerFlags = "-lz -lsqlite3", IsCxx = true)]
```

Device: iPhone 5s

Xamarin Studio: 5.9.7 (build 9)

Tested on Simulators: 5, 5s, 6 with sdk 8.4 i 8.1

"lipo -info libPaylevenSDK.a" gives me: Architectures in the fat file: libPaylevenSDK.a are: i386 x86_64 armv7 arm64

and

"lipo -info libAdyenToolkit.a" : Architectures in the fat file: libAdyenToolkit.a are: i386 x86_64 armv7 armv7s arm64

Comment: post the code /Users/Admin/myApp/ViewController/PinView.cs:36 that is in this class

Comment: 36 Request = new MvxViewModelRequest<PinViewModel>(null, null, new MvxRequestedBy());

Comment: my mistake, I was on another branch, in line 36 is "var pm = new PaylevenManeger();" This is code PaylevenManeger: http://pastebin.com/x2jQRdNE

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have got an undefined symbol exception, you probably has your .a file built only for simulator. You can know it exactly if you run

```
nm %yourLibrary%.a | grep _SecCertificateCreateWithData
```

and find there only one line for one architecture.

Build one more library, for devices, and merge them with lipo like here:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/native_interop/

Comment: "lipo -info libPaylevenSDK.a" gives me:
Architectures in the fat file: libPaylevenSDK.a are: i386 x86_64 armv7 arm64

Comment: "nm libPaylevenSDK.a | grep _SecCertificateCreateWithData" gives me:
"            U _SecCertificateCreateWithData"

Comment: This way it just doesn't see this method and it's a Xamarin bug. If you clean project, restart everything and still get this then write to their support.